# Tag innertext not displayed in label box in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string a;
a = "vimal < kumar>";        
Label1.Text = a;
}
```

Output:

```
vimal
```

`Tag( <ABCDE> )` inner text why not displayed in label box (ASP.NET),

Actual result is `vimal <kumar>` 
but the `vimal` only displayed, tag inner text not displayed

Comment: what's asp.nae? A typo or a framework?

Comment: @Vimalkumar: I suggest you learn basic HTML.

Answer (score 2):

you must use the html encoded variant of the string. HtmlEncode will do the trick.

(there is also UrlEncode for encoding Url's)

```
 Dim test = "This is an <little>test</little>"
 test = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because < and > together are HTML Tags. You'll need to use their ascii representations if you don't want them to be hidden.